# Worksheetfunction.average returning error when range contains empty cells or cells with text

Tags: excel, vba

I am dealing with small ranges (only one column) that can contain both numbers and text (or empty cells). The description of the `worksheetfunction.average` says that "Arguments can either be numbers or names, arrays, or references that contain numbers." and "If an array or reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored." It says too that "Empty cells are not counted, but zero values are."

However,

```
With Sh 
SlpStdBlkCorr_Sh.Range("T2") = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(RawPb208Range)) 
End with
```

raises the "**unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class**" error.

This line of code is used repeatedly, so all variables are perfectly set and this error only raises when the range has empty cells or cells with text.

Shouldn't the `.average` ignore these cells with non-numeric contents?

I have tried the solution by [Paul Aford](http://excelvbaerror.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/runtime-error-1004-unable-to-get.html), but the problem is that as I am calculating somethings and I can create some monsters just equaling variables to 0 (`SlpStdBlkCorr_Sh.Range("T2")=0`) or 1 (`SlpStdBlkCorr_Sh.Range("T2")=1`).

Ideas?

Comment: A line of code I tested just now,  "Application.WorksheetFunction.Average (ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6"))", works perfectly fine on a range with numbers, blanks, and text. You should give us more info if you really need help.

Comment: This problem will apear when there is no any numeric value in range

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, I tried using your line of code in my worksheet, while in break mode, and the result was the same as I described before. I tried to the end the code and then run again your code, but the same error message raised. Maybe something related to the cell format?

Comment: @Felipe  I've read your comment below about the csv file. No, this would not cause the problem (I've tested this a minute ago). If you have cells with numbers, regardless of cell formating, you are good. What do you have in those cells, anyhow? An example of a cell contents with a number (as it looks in the formula bar)?

Comment: @geneskuratovsky, here goes an example. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84eLpq7CTSadFpnZTNJY0Y4bXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Felipe You did not show the view of a cell in the Formula Bar but it is clear to me from the captured image you linked in here that it is all OK. I do not think I can do anything more without having a detailed view of the "big picture": at the minimum, all the code involed in this sequence, but perhaps even more. Effective troubleshooting is a skill one develops "through adversity", alas. Good luck to you.

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, you can download this workbook, there is an arrow at the top of the window.

Comment: @Felipe ...of course, but this is the data (there is nothing wrong with it, BTW). I was talking about a comprehansive look at the code you run.

Comment: @Felipe From what you have written, and posted, there does not seem to be a problem with your data. That leaves a problem with your code, perhaps in how you have defined your range.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing it errors only when the range contains **only** non-numeric values and/or blank cells. This matches the behavior of the `AVERAGE` function in a worksheet. If you use have a formula with, for example, `=AVERAGE(A1:A10)` and those cells are all non-numeric or blank, it will return "#DIV/0".

This makes sense since with no numerics there's nothing to divide by, so the denominator is zero.

Here's a worksheet selection  change event you can use to test this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Count function returns cells with numeric values    
If WorksheetFunction.Count(Selection) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Average(Selection)
Else
    Debug.Print "Nothing to Average"
End If
End Sub
```

Note that you'll see the same error message if one or more cells in the range has a formula that returns an error, such as `#N/A`.

Comment: You are correct, of course, but this is not quite what the OP complained about/puzzled over, is it? He never mentioned "no numeric values in the range"--just a minor thing, this is :)

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, I think it does address the OP's question. (Hopefully we'll find out.) They said "this error only raises when the range has empty cells or cells with text". I think the problem probably only occurs when range contains only empty cells or cells with text. (Alternatively, the same error can occur when one or more cells in the range has a formula error, like #N/A, but that does seem less likely to me.)

Comment: @DougGlancy, you understood my problem, but it happen in range with a mix of cells with numbers and cells with text or empty. I'm always saying empty OR text because filling them with text or trying to clear theirs contents were my attempts to solve this problem. Something that I realized right now is that the workbook causing all this trouble is a tab delimited file that I open using VBA and use to calculate my stuff. Is this relevant? Using the code of GeneSkuratovsky in a different opened workbook doesn't raise the error.

Comment: Try an `AVERAGE` formula in the workbook itself on a range that's giving you the problem in VBA. I assume the worksheet formula will return #DIV/0. My guess is that the numbers are actually imported as text.

Comment: @DougGlancy, I tried just like GeneSkuratovsky said in his first comment but the result was similar, with just the difference that now, after stopping the program, the average function works perfectly. There is some factor influencing this situation that I didn't notice yet, maybe something that my program does before arrive at this point. Take a look at the example that I posted above. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when all the cells are empty.  If at least one of them isn't blank, it works as advertised.

Starting at column AA in groups of 5, where arr is an array and 'row' is a passed-in argument.

```
    c = 27 ' column AA
    For i = 0 To 9 ' for 10 groups
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range(Cells(row, c), Cells(row, c + 4))) < 5 Then
            arr(i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(row, c), Cells(row, c + 4)))
            c = c + 5
        End If
    Next i
```